# How to transform XML to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I'm using C# Asp.Net, VisualStudio 2012, and I try to consume one webservice. The webservice return one XML, even though, the method name was arrayExtratoPedido.

Here is the webservice method:

```cs
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return")]
public retExtratoPedidos extratoCompras(string codigoClubeST, string dataInicial, string dataFinal) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("extratoCompras", new object[] {
                codigoClubeST,
                dataInicial,
                dataFinal});
    return ((retExtratoPedidos)(results[0]));
}
```

I try to get the result in TList.

I try to use this:

```cs
var compras = Client.extratoCompras("288889", dtInicialStr, dtFinalStr);
var pedido = compras.arrayExtratoPedidos;
var listaPedido = pedido.Any.ToArray();
```

and this:

```cs
var compras = Client.extratoCompras("288889", dtInicialStr, dtFinalStr);
var pedido = compras.arrayExtratoPedidos;
var listaPedido = pedido.Any.ToList();
```

But **listaPedido** doesn't have a IList to interate..

When I debug, I get this:

```cs
listaPedido {System.Xml.XmlElement[2]}
  -> [0] {Element, Name="ns1:arrayExtratoPedidos"}
  -> [1] {Element, Name="ns1:arrayExtratoPedidos"}
```

and in the **innerText** this:

```cs
<torcedor>29</torcedor><data_pedido>2014-01-20</data_pedido><pedido>4697</pedido><canal>Internet</canal><codigo_partida>5514</codigo_partida><data_partida>2014-01-23</data_partida><clube_local>Botafogo</clube_local><clube_visitante>Madureira</clube_visitante><estadio>São Januário</estadio><setor>Cadeira Social Inferior A</setor><fileira>-</fileira><cadeira>10</cadeira><tipo_ingresso>I</tipo_ingresso><valor>50</valor><valor_pago>0</valor_pago><usado>false</usado>
```

Edited:

```cs
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfarrayExtratoPedidos arrayExtratoPedidos {
        get {
            return this.arrayExtratoPedidosField;
        }
        set {
            this.arrayExtratoPedidosField = value;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion to get List in these case?

Thanks

Comment: why are you using the any condition prior to the ToList() extension methond? try var listaPedido = pedido.ToList();

Comment: If I remove Any(), doesn't compile. When remove Any, only accept ToList(). to get ToList(), I have to use Any().

Comment: what's the returning type of "extratoCompras"?

Comment: when you say "If I remove Any(), doesn't compile" what's the compilation error you get?

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'FCard.ArrayOfarrayExtratoPedidos' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can you update your question and add the "arrayExtratoPedidos" definiton?

Comment: @Pedro I edit and added the definition.